# Как подрезать картинку так, чтобы сохранить адаптивность?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, svg

Есть картинка на всю ширину, которая подрезается внизу неравномерными треугольниками (от края до края) со смещением от центра.
Как сделать средствами `css` так, чтобы эта структура была адаптивной на любых разрешениях экрана и сохраняла свою форму?
 Если невозможно с помощью стилей, то как сделать подобное хотя бы с `js` не подключая внешние библиотеки? [Фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/hdntj97s/7/)

```css
section img {
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -83px;
  left: 0;
  border: 80px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 350px solid #fff;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -94px;
  left: 350px;
  border: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 290px solid #fff;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<section><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x150"></section>
<div></div>
```

Comment: я просто объясню - вырезаете картинку в растре - это будет самый низ - и абсолютно эту картинку расположите в самом низу блока (в котором картинка) - понимаете ?

Comment: @Максим Ленский я-то понимаю, но как вы считаете, для чего были придуманы все варианции с `css3` фигурами, svg векторы и т.п. ? Может быть стоило продолжать по старинке везде растр использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так можно тоже делать

высота регулируется `transparent` углом

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  border-left: 50vw solid #fff;
  border-right: 50vw solid #fff;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x300/cc00cc" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: супер! то, что нужно. Единственное, такой момент - у border-top 100px и из-за этого картинка вылазит за горизонтальные рамки. Уменьшил на 2vw у border-right и border-top назначил вместо этого 5vw и вроде как на моем разрегиении экрана все стало норм, но не знаю - адаптивно ил это и кроссбраузерно?

Comment: самое лучшее это svg - но и такой подход имеет место быть - если хочешь я добавлю второй вариант с svg

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с SVG

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 583 371">

  <defs>
    <clipPath  id="clipPath841" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path id="path843"
         d="m -397.63094,215.35715 h 582.08332 v 281.66158 l -286.68593,88.75509 -295.39739,-88.75509 z"
         style="fill:#ff5555;" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(397.63094,-215.35715)">
    <image
       clip-path="url(#clipPath841)"
       width="583.59521"
       height="370.41666"
       preserveAspectRatio="none"
       style="image-rendering:optimizeQuality"
       xlink:href="https://wallbox.ru/wallpapers/main/201304/87cf2bd21fe79a7.jpg"
       id="image823"
       x="-397.63095"
       y="215.35715" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: а чтобы управлять направлением сдвига - какие параметры для этого менять?

Comment: @Вася там координаты в `d` их надо менять ... это надо показывать...или воспользоваться векторным редактором

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 450px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 90%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 90%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Вот [ссылочка](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) на онлайн редактор.
Вот только с IE не дружит или это IE не имеет друзей =).